# How i can insert a spinner selected item into mysql database for mobile app?

Tags: android, database, android-spinner

I am fetching the values from database into `Spinner` its working but I want to insert selected item from `Spinner` into database, how can I do this?

I am using two `Spinners` and both `Spinner's` selected item should insert into database.

How to do this and what I need to do to insert item in `PHP`?

**Activity Class:-**

```
 public class MainActivity_d2 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    //Declaring an Spinner
   private Spinner spinner2, spinner1;

    //An ArrayList for Spinner Items

    private ArrayList<String> students1;
    private ArrayList<String> students2;

    //JSON Array

    private JSONArray result1, result2, result;

    //TextViews to display details
    private TextView textViewName1;
    private TextView textViewName2;
    private TextView textViewCourse;
    private TextView textViewSession;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_d1);

        //Initializing the ArrayList
        students1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        students2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Initializing Spinner


        //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
        //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener


        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        //    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Initializing TextViews
        textViewName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName1);
        textViewName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName2);
        //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
        //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

        //This method will fetch the data from the URL

        getData1();
        getData2();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    /*    switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.spinner1:
                getData1();
                break;


            case R.id.spinner2:
                getData2();
                break;
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


        if (spinner1.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {
            //do this
            textViewName1.setText("");
        } else if (spinner2.getId() == R.id.spinner2) {
            //do this
            textViewName2.setText("");
        }

    }

    private void getData1() {
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response1) {
                        JSONObject j1 = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j1 = new JSONObject(response1);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result1 = j1.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY1);

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getStudents1(result1);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);
    }

    private void getStudents1(JSONArray j1) {
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j1.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json1 = j1.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students1.add(json1.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d2.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students1));
    }

//Initializing TextViews

//      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
//      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

//This method will fetch the data from the URL

 private void getData2() {
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL2,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response2) {
                        JSONObject j2 = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j2 = new JSONObject(response2);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j2.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getStudents2(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);
    }

    private void getStudents2(JSONArray j2) {
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j2.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json2 = j2.getJSONObject(i);

                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                students2.add(json2.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d2.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the spinner selected item in sqlite then follow this code
1.create a local db
2.In your activity inserted the selected values as follows.

LocalDatabase:

```
public class SpinnerDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerModule";

// Labels table name
private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "spinner";

// Labels Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_SPINONE = "spinone";
private static final String KEY_SPINTWO = "spintwo";
SQLiteDatabase db;

public LoginDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Category table create query
    String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_SPINONE + " TEXT,"           
            
            + KEY_SPINTWO + " TEXT" + ");";


    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
public void insertLabel(String spinone,String spintwo){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(KEY_ID,id);
    values.put(KEY_SPINONE,spinone);
    values.put(KEY_SPINTWO,spintwo);
   
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

}

To insert the values into sqlite from your activity as
1.Initialize the sqlite database in your mainactivity as

```
SpinnerDatabaseHandler db=new SpinnerDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext);
```

2.After that add these codes

```
 String firstspin=spinner1.getSelectedItem.toString();
 String secondspin=spinner2.getSelectedItem.toString();
 db.insertlabel(firstspin,secondspin);
```

Comment: please give me a code for php mysql to insert selected item into database.what can i do for this in php and java, please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have Save/OK button for insert spinner selected item into database.

**Get spinner selected item value**

```
String spinner1SlctdVal = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Course spinner
String spinner2SlctdVal = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(); // Username spinner
```

**For insert spinner selected item in PHP**

```
you have to call PHP web-service using AsyncTask or other methods.
```

After selection values from both spinner when User click on Save/OK button below code is execute.

Code for Save/OK button click:

```
mBtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        String spinner1SlctdVal = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String spinner2SlctdVal = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // Insert spinner selected values in database
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("course", spinner1SlctdVal); // "course" is column name of your table
        values.put("username", spinner2SlctdVal); // "username" is column name of your table
        database.insert("users", null, values); // "users" is your table name
        database.close();

        // Call AsynTask or other method for call web-service (for insert selected values into PHP server)
    }
});
```

Comment: please tell me entire query for insert that selected item into PHP server

Comment: I am using mysql database please give me suggestion for mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

Php file to insert the values:

```
<?php
     $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST';
     define('HOST','hostname');
     define('USER','username');
     define('PASS','password');
     define('DB','databasename'); 
     $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 

    $firstspin=$_POST['lspinone'];
    $secondspin=$_POST['lspintwo'];



     $query = "INSERT INTO `spinnertable` (`spione`, `spintwo`) VALUES ('".$firstspin."', '".$secondspin."')";
     $inserted = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
     if($inserted == 1 ){
                    echo "success";
                }else{
                    echo "user exist already";
                }
                mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Code for passing values from android to php:

```
package nidhinkumar.gridcam.logindetails;

public class MainPAge extends AppCompatActivity{
private static final String LOGINALL_URL =   "http://smpleuser.com/07032016/php/nameofphpfile.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinnerpage);
    String spinone=spinner1.getSelectedItem.toString();
    Stirng spintwo=spinner2.getSelectedItem.toString();

    // Call AsyncTask for send selected value to PHP server. 
    userSpinnr(spinone, spintwo);
} 



private void userSpinnr(final String lspinone, final String lspintwo) {
    rando=(int)(Math.random()*10);
    class LoginSpinners extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            loading = ProgressDialog.show(LoginPage.this, "Do you know?", "", true, false);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                //do the action what you want
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }


            }else{                    
                    loading.dismiss();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("lspinone",params[0]);
            data.put("lspintwo",params[1]);

            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(LOGINALL_URL,data);
            return result;
        }
    }
    LoginSpinners ulc = new LoginSpinners();
    ulc.execute(lspinone,lspintwo);

}
```

}

Comment: i want to chose spinner item then selected item insert in to php mysql db using onItemSelectedListener how to do?

Comment: can you explain it detailed

Comment: Call  userSpinnr(spinone, spintwo); method on Save/Ok button click event.
Please review my answer, when you find button click event and add below code at last line of button onClick() event.
**userSpinnr(spinner1SlctdVal , spinner2SlctdVal );**

Comment: I used two spinners one for 'username' and second for 'course'. I stored it in db, I retrieving spinners data from mysql database its works fine! now i want to select item from spinners, when I click on submit button then selected item should be inserted into a mysql db......please give me php and java code

Comment: Mukund - You have to combine my answer code (get selected value from spinner on save button click) and @NidhinKumar code (send selected value of spinner to PHP mysql database.)