# how i can insert a spinner selected item in mysql php in android studio?

Tags: android, mysql

I used two spinners one for 'username' and second for 'course'. I stored it in db, I retrieving spinners data from mysql database its works fine! now i want to select item from spinners, when I click on submit button then selected item should be inserted into a mysql db.please give me php and java code.
    //java file

```
    public class MainActivity_d3 extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        //Declaring an Spinner
        private Spinner spinner2, spinner1;
        private String str_spinner1, str_spinner2, s_name, s_course;
        //An ArrayList for Spinner Items

        private ArrayList<String> students1;
        private ArrayList<String> students2;

        Button mBtnSave;

        //JSON Array

        private JSONArray result1, result2, result;

        //TextViews to display details
        private TextView textViewName1;
        private TextView textViewName2;
        private TextView textViewCourse;
        private TextView textViewSession;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_d1);

            //Initializing the ArrayList
            students1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            students2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Initializing Spinner


            //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
            //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener


            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            //    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            mBtnSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

            mBtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String str_spinner1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String str_spinner2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                }
            });

            //Initializing TextViews
            textViewName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName1);
            textViewName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName2);
            //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
            //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

            //This method will fetch the data from the URL

            getData1();
            getData2();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


          if(spinner1.getId()==R.id.spinner1) {
                str_spinner1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
            else if(spinner2.getId()==R.id.spinner2)
            {
                str_spinner2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
                  /*    switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.spinner1:
                    getData1();
                    break;


                case R.id.spinner2:
                    getData2();
                    break;
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            if (spinner1.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {
                //do this
                textViewName1.setText("");
            } else if (spinner2.getId() == R.id.spinner2) {
                //do this
                textViewName2.setText("");
            }

        }

        private void getData1() {
            //Creating a string request
            StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL1,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response1) {
                            JSONObject j1 = null;
                            try {
                                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                j1 = new JSONObject(response1);

                                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                result1 = j1.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY1);

                                //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                getStudents1(result1);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Creating a request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);
        }

        private void getStudents1(JSONArray j1) {
            //Traversing through all the items in the json array
            for (int i = 0; i < j1.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    //Getting json object
                    JSONObject json1 = j1.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Adding the name of the student to array list
                    students1.add(json1.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
                   spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d3.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students1));
        }

    //Initializing TextViews

    //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
    //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

    //This method will fetch the data from the URL

        private void getData2() {
            //Creating a string request
            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL2,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response2) {
                            JSONObject j2 = null;
                            try {
                                //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                j2 = new JSONObject(response2);

                                //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                result = j2.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                                //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                getStudents2(result);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                        }
                    });

            //Creating a request queue
            RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            //Adding request to the queue
            requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);
        }

        private void getStudents2(JSONArray j2) {
            //Traversing through all the items in the json array
            for (int i = 0; i < j2.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    //Getting json object
                    JSONObject json2 = j2.getJSONObject(i);

                    //Adding the name of the student to array list
                    students2.add(json2.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
            spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_d3.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not tell what your problem exactly is. Dont you know how to upload some strings to php? Or dont you know how to get the selected text from a spinner?

Comment: My problem is i want to insert spinner selected item in mysql db,how to i store this selectd item in mysql db using php mysql?

Comment: Why did you post all that irrelevant code to get data from an url?.

Comment: So you can send the sptinner text  strings to the php script already? So you only need a php script. Why then ask for java code? You did not give new info. You only repeated what you want. We knew that already.

Comment: then what i exactly do here?

Comment: You should answer my questions. So we know what you can do and where the problem is. Look at my first comment.

Comment: i dont know how to upload selected item string to php, please suggest.

Comment: You have asked this already today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451202 And got a lot of answers. It's unbelievable that you post a bunch of irelevant code again. You are helped very well in that other post and should have sticked to some detail problems. And certainly here if you do not know how to send some data to a php script.